# In MarkLogic should you close EvaluResultIterator if it is unused or contains the empty sequence?

Tags: java, java-8, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I am using the java-api from MarkLogic to evaluate XQueries. Sometimes these XQueries return nothing(the empty sequence) or the result is not used.

According to the documentation(https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/eval/ServerEvaluationCall.html):

> NOTE: EvalResultIterator MUST BE CLOSED. If you call eval() don't forget to call close() on the returned EvalResultIterator to free up the underlying resources.

Of course this does not look very nice when you do this with an empty try with resources

```
try (EvalResultIterator eval = invoker.eval()) {
    // No result is returned    
}
```

Is it really necessary to close the EvalResultIterator in this case and what is the best way to do so?

Comment: "Returns empty" and "result is unused" are two very different cases. If you know for certain that you're only evaluating for side effects, why not just call `invoker.eval().close()`?

Comment: During evaluation exceptions can occur. So i want to ensure that the  resource is closed.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, then no `EvalResultIterator` will be returned _to_ close.

Comment: That is probably the correct answer. If you post it i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `invoker.eval().close()`. If `invoker.eval()` throws an exception, then no `EvalResultIterator` will be returned *to* close, so no need to worry about a `finally` block.